# 'Could not resolve matching constructor' when auto-generating RepositoryImpl through Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Jpa to automatically generate a class to implement my repository.

But when I was trying to start the container it told me `Error creating bean with name 'accountRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor`.

My `Account` entity:

```
package com.amastigote.ssp.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by hwding on 3/22/17.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String nickName;
    private String plainPassword;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(String nickName, String plainPassword) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.plainPassword = plainPassword;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public String getPlainPassword() {
        return plainPassword;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Repository interface for `Account`:

```
package com.amastigote.ssp.repo;

import com.amastigote.ssp.model.Account;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * Created by hwding on 3/22/17.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}
```

Jpa Configure:

```
package com.amastigote.ssp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Created by hwding on 3/23/17.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.amastigote.ssp.repo")
public class JPAConf {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(
            DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                .setDataSource(dataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                .setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPackagesToScan("com.amastigote.ssp.model");

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is ambiguous in fact, for that I'm using a low version of `spring-data-jpa` (which is recommended by my IDE...).

After adding the newest version to my project, a more specific hint was given:

```
error when creating inner bean '...', 
could not found bean named 'entityManagerFactoryBean'.
```

I noticed that my entity factory bean is configured like:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(...) {}
```

By default its bean name is 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', which does not match the demanded `entityManagerFactoryBean`.

The Solution is to add `entityManagerFactoryRef = "localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"` to your `@EnableJpaRepositories`, like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.amastigote.ssp.repo",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
)
```