# Upgrading Spring data jpa and commons causes 'Could not resolve matching constructor' on repository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Upgrading Spring Data Jpa from 1.6.5.RELEASE to 1.7.4.RELEASE and Spring Data Commons from 1.8.5.RELEASE to 1.9.4.RELEASE, I'm getting the following error at startup:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint:
> specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type
> ambiguities)

Since myRepository is an interface ( extending JpaRepository ), it is unclear how to specify a constructor for this class.
How can I resolve this issue or investigate further?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Please format it as code, not as a quote for easier reading.

Are you managing the dependencies explicitly? It is recommended to just specify the desired version of Spring Data JPA and let it pull in commons on its own.

Comment: Your error is the same as mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968346/could-not-resolve-matching-constructor-when-auto-generating-repositoryimpl-thr . Perhaps you have a similar bean configuration problem.

Comment: Share your project through github to resolve this issue.

Comment: @JensSchauder Your suggestion solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the answer of Jens Schauder, I let spring-data-jpa pull the version of spring-data-commons instead of hardcoding it. It solved my issues.